# Change internal link labels in Sphinx

Tags: python, hyperlink, python-sphinx, sections, toctree

I'm generating documentation with [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/). I can change the label of links to documents in the table of contents with

```
Features </resources/pages/features>
```

in the toctree directive as per [the toctree directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree),  but how can I do the same for links to sections **within** a document?

EDIT :

This is what I would like to achieve :

doc.rst

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    Section - Information <info>

.. _info:

Info Section
------------
```

So that `Section - information` would appear in the table of contents but `Info section` would appear in the document itself

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use standard reST labels.

Example:

pages/features.rst:

```
.. _label1:

A section
---------

Some text
```

otherpage.rst:

```
See :ref:`label1`
```

[Cross-referencing arbitrary locations](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations).

Comment: How can I do that within the documents' toctree directive though?

Comment: Not sure if what you want is possible using toctree. Perhaps you should just create the table of contents manually?